# Is it ok to configure a logger to log to standard out?

Tags: java, logging, log4j, slf4j

I am surprised that i wasn't able to find a clear answer on this with some google searches. I understand in java that you are not supposed to use System.out.println for several reasons. But I am wondering if this also means that you shouldn't log to standard out from a logger such as log4j or slf4j. I believe this is ok from a performance point of view but maybe there are other reasons this is not ok. Is this good practice or not? ... Thanks in advance.

Comment: During development your eyes are on the screen. When in production, you will need to acquire a monkey (probably illegally) to watch streams of log lines go through the screen.

Comment: What kind of setup? Type of application, of user, environment. A log will be useless garbage for a final user, he will not understand anything and at worst he will believe that he has broken anything and ask for support. As stated, a daemon process will have no one reading it. Do not try to replace proper UI with a log.

Comment: And even as a developer, I find files way more useful. I do not have to worry about the text scrolling up as more logs are printed, or the required lines getting outside the console buffer. I can open the file in a text editor and search to my heart's content. And if I wish to read the log file in the console, I can do `tail -f` whenever I want to.

Answer (score 1):

Especially if you are on unix, it's actually situationally a *GOOD* idea to log to standard out. That way, whoever invoked your application can see the stream and possibly save it, pipe it somewhere else, etc.

---- Edit ----

Re: why use designated log files...

Servlet app servers are an example of good reasons to use designated log files.

These are just a few of the reasons that are coming to mind:

1. There's different kind of data logged in separate files / streams
2. Web servers are often run automatically as system services, so there's not as much advantage of logging to standard out
3. When you are more likely to want to go through the log manually, rather than doing automated analysis / response
4. When there are business or legal obligations to treat the data in a certain way

Comment: Is this in addition to log files? I guess my next question would be why use designated log files vs standard out?

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, unless you are working on a local project or a in a POC, it is always better to use a Logger, saving log files and managing all this stuff related to log for you instead the System.out. Why? First depending where you application will be deployed, you don't know what exactly is the System.out. In you local machine normally it will be the terminal or the IDE console for example, but in a environment where you don't have control, you cannot assume that. Second, sometimes you know where your log streams are but you don't have access. For example, if the security team of your client set the System.out to point out a place that a few people have access.